# Forcefully initialize class with unavailable init in Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, screencapturekit

The [SCWindow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screencapturekit/scwindow) class has all its initializers marked as unavailable. In Objective-C, I can get around it using class extensions:

```objectivec
#import <ScreenCaptureKit/ScreenCaptureKit.h>

@interface SCWindow (InitWithId)

@property CGWindowID windowID;

- (instancetype _Nonnull)initWithId:(CGWindowID)windowID;

@end

@implementation SCWindow (InitWithId)

@dynamic windowID;

- (instancetype _Nonnull)initWithId:(CGWindowID)windowID {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:windowID] forKey:@"windowID"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Is there a technique to do this in Swift? I believe Swift extensions only allow `convenience` initializers, not designated ones like Objective-C.

Comment: Doesn't look trustworthy even in Objective-C. Are you sure that just using own class with `@property CGWindowID windowID;` won't be enough?

Comment: Why are you trying to instantiate a class that doesn't have a public initializer? The initialisers are not public for a reason - `SCWindow` should only be initialised by the system.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I tried just using that, but the program kept crashing. Maybe the internal implementation has checks to prevent using the setter?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Honestly, I'm just not satisfied with `SCShareableContent` since it doesn't return the windows in z-index order. I'm using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` to do this.

Comment: Can't you get the `SCWindow`s from `SCShareableContent` and handle them in the order from `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`?

Comment: @Willeke True. I think I was originally concerned about the extra complexity but I'll test it out.